# matlab normpdf not working on double

Tags: matlab, normal-distribution

I'm running matlab 2013b and when I use normpdf(0.1,0.1,0.1) it informs me that "Undefinded function 'normpdf' for intput arguments of type 'double'. Using which normpdf shows that normpdf is installed within my toolbox does anybody know what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does `which -all normpdf` actually return? Does it actually point to the function from the statistics toolbox? You can also try `edit normpdf` to see which file gets opened in the editor.

Normally, the first input to `normpdf` is a vector or matrix of values, the second and third input scalar (although they can also be vectors or matrices). See [documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/stats/normpdf.html) for more details.

Comment: It returns C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\stats\normpdf.m %has no license avaible. Is that a problem?

Comment: Yes, it means you don't have a license for the Statistics toolbox, so you can't use any function from that toolbox. What does `ver` return?

Comment: You can also check which toolboxes you have licenses for (they normally should be the same as the toolboxes which are installed) by looking at your license file: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/solutions/en/data/1-63ZIR6/. It lists the licensed toolboxes as "INCREMENT" lines.

Comment: Alright I contacted my universities support and somehow something went wrong with my liscencing, Thanks